# How to encapsulate properly in C# so Main cannot change values

Tags: c#, coordinates, encapsulation

I have one seemingly simple question about encapsulation in C#.

In one of our school assignments, we're supposed to create a simple two dimensional coordination calculation system, and encapsulate the files correctly, so that we cannot edit the position or length of the points from the Main method.

I created two C# files, namely Line and Point. The file Program.cs was given to us, so we're supposed to work around that, and we're not allowed to change any code in that file. The file we're supposed to encapsulate is the Line.cs or Point.cs files, so that the Main method cannot edit the position of the points from there by writing e.g. `p1.X = 0;`.
Below are the files that I've written so far:

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using coordinationSystem;
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Point p0 = new Point();
        Point p1 = new Point(-10, -10);
        Console.WriteLine("Point p0, position = (" + p0.X + ", " + p0.Y + ")");
        Console.WriteLine("Point p1, position = (" + p1.X + ", " + p1.Y + ")");

        Line theLine = new Line(p0, p1); //This is the correct line.
        outdata("Print 1 of the line", theLine);

        p1.X = 0; //This is the thing I'm trying to prevent...
        outdata("Print 2 of the line", theLine);

        Point startposition = theLine.Position();
        startposition.Y = 5; //... same with this one
        outdata("Print 3 of the line", theLine);
    }
    private static void outdata(string text, Line theLine)
    {
        double length = theLine.Length();
        Point startPos = theLine.Position();
        Console.WriteLine("\n" + text);
        Console.WriteLine("==================================");
        Console.WriteLine("Length = {0 :f4} units", length);
        Console.WriteLine("Position = ({0},{1})", startPos.X, startPos.Y);
        Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------");
    }
}
```

**Point.cs**

```
namespace coordinationSystem
{
    public class Point
    {
        private int x, y;

        public Point() : this(0, 0) { } //Default-constructor.

        public Point(int X, int Y) //Constructor.
        {
            this.X = X;
            this.Y = Y;
        }

        public int X //Property for the X-coordinate.
        {
            get { return x; }
            set
            {
                x = value;
            }
        }

        public int Y //Property for the Y-coordinate.
        {
            get { return y; }
            set
            {
                y = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Line.cs**

```
using System;

namespace coordinationSystem
{
    public class Line
    {
        private Point p0;
        private Point p1;

        public Line(Point p0, Point p1)
        {
            this.p0 = p0;
            this.p1 = p1;
        }
        public double Length()
        {
            double pointLength = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(p0.X - p1.X, 2) + Math.Pow(p0.Y - p1.Y, 2));
            return pointLength;
        }
        public Point Position()
        {
            return p0;
        }
    }
}
```

I came to the conclusion that I should probably use `get` and `set`, but this hasn't worked out for me since the `theLine.Position();` in Main is a method (and as I wrote earlier, we're not supposed to edit the Program.cs/Main at all).

So is there any ideas here? Any help will be much appreciated!

EDIT:

This is the assignment text (loosely translated from Swedish):

> Consider whether it is possible to sabotage the line if you have
>   access to references to the lines both endpoints. What happens, for
>   example, with the line if you would change the p0 or p1 in the Main
>   method after you have created the line? What happens to the line when
>   you move the starting position in the Main method? Modify the code in
>   the class Line and Point so that the above problems are avoided.

Comment: If you're not meant to change `Main`, then how do you hope to "prevent" `p1.X = 0`? Do you want it to not compile, or something else? (Btw, now would be a good time to learn about automatically implemented properties...)

Comment: the lines you have commented both access Point.cs and not Line.cs.

Comment: You're probably right, I should change that so that both Line.cs and Point.cs can be edited. My bad.

Comment: This is a terrible homework assignment!

Comment: I know, our teacher is a little... Well :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that problem has multiple solutions, here are two:

1-Convert Point to an struct.

Structs are pased by value, not by reference, so when you return p0 on the method it will be a copy, if anyone changes the returned point the original line will remain unchanged.

2-Duplicate the point.

Instead of returning p0 directly, just return new Point(p0.X, p0.Y), it will have the same result as 1

Anyway, try to get your teacher fired, she doesn't knows C#, she knows Java and thus she doesn't understand how properties work as any C# programmer would use properties and not functions to retrieve properties from a higer class like Line.

EDIT: If you use method 2 then also clone the points used on the constructor of Line:

```
    public Line(Point p0, Point p1)
    {
        this.p0 = new Point(p0.X, p0.Y);
        this.p1 = new Point(p1.X, p0.Y);
    }
```

Comment: Well, I successfully returned the Position method correctly by using 

`public Punkt Position()
        {
            return new Punkt(p0.X, p0.Y);
        }`

However, now I just have to make sure that `p1.X = 0;` in the Main metod doesn't change the calculation! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! This did it. Now the Main method won't change it's calculation of the line despite having `p1.X = 0;` or `startposition.Y = 5;` in it's method.

Answer (score 2):

> Modify the code in the class Line and Point so that the above problems
>   are avoided.

To avoid the problem of access from Main method, it is best to prevent it at compile time, so desired modification would be as following.

Use `private set` for properties :

```
public int X //Property for the X-coordinate.
{
    get { return x; }
    private set
    {
        x = value;
    }
}

public int Y //Property for the Y-coordinate.
{
    get { return y; }
    private set
    {
        y = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: That didn't work, since then the Main method apparently cannot reach the property of `p1.X = 0;` or `startposition.Y = 5;`.

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? preventing Main method to change values

Comment: I guess you can throw an exception if a modification attempt is made, but honestly, that's just awful programming. I'm not so sure about this homework assignment...

Comment: Well yes, but I'm thrown with this error: `The property or indexer 'Point.X' cannot be used in this context because the set accessor is inaccessible.`

Comment: As you are not required to change anything from Main class. What I get from your question is that your instructor wants you to change other classes so the Main method code doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Well, we're supposed to change the other classes so that you cannot edit the code by writing e.g. `startposition.Y = 5;` in the Main method. I know it sound weird, thought so too.

Comment: @tobulos1, I would make sure that's exactly what you are being asked, as it's a very strange request. What Umair posted is what a normal class would be like.

Comment: @tobulos1 compiler error that you can see is a good way to prevent main method to change value. you can throw a runtime exception as well but I am not sure if that's what you require.

Comment: I just added the assignment text if you want to take a look at it.

Comment: @tobulos1 I was right about it. you are required to prevent the code compilation if Main method code is changing the properties.

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't change the obviously broken code in `Main()`, you are left with basically two options:

1. Throw exception in the `set` accessor.
2. Do nothing in the `set` accessor (that is, don't actually change the value).

It would look like this

```
public int X {
    get {
        return x;
    }
    set {
        // do nothing
    }
}
```

Or:

```
public int X {
    get {
        return x;
    }
    set {
        throw new Exception("Cannot change value of X");
    }
}
```

You'd do the same for Y and the other properties.

Comment: But what if he wants to access setter from some other classes. if setter always throw exception then whats the point of having setter at all?

Comment: This is correct, although this would be a very strange. But hey, the assignment is strange to begin with (it's like the classes are fighting each other).

Comment: @UmairM: I agree, but the homework assignment, which is, IMHO, a pretty bad one, requires this. The only way to make the the Point and Line classes not changeable, but still have the code compile, is to make the setters not actually change the values.

Comment: @siride I guess for a home work assignment, compile time prevention is more appropriate than a run-time exception.

Answer (score 0):

use same as with y property.

public class Point
    {
        private int x, y;

```
    public Point() : this(0, 0) { } //Default-constructor.

    public Point(int X, int Y) //Constructor.
    {
        //this.X = X;
        //this.Y = Y;
        setx(X);
        //this.y = Y;
    }

    public int X //Property for the X-coordinate.
    {
        get { return x; }
        private set
        {
            x = value;
        }

    }

    public int Y //Property for the Y-coordinate.
    {
        get { return y; }
    }

    public int setx(int Xvalue)
    {
        return x = Xvalue;
    }
}
```